# Predefined function to use in ng-repeat nested in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a list directive that basically get all the items from a service and show them in a table. When I click on an item in the table, it opens a form in relation with the type of item.

Everything works great, but now, I have one instance of that list where I need to override the event when I click on an item. So I added an attribute in the directive:

```
<list factory-name="Workers"
      on-item-click="$state.go('worker.workerDetails', {workerId: item._id})">
</list>
```

So when I get to the function that gets called when I click an item, I can do something like that:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="edit(item)></tr>

$scope.edit = function(item) {
  if ($attrs.onItemClick) {
    setTimeout(function(){ $scope.$apply($attrs.onItemClick); });
  } else {
    edit(item);
  }
};
```

The problem is that I cannot isolate the scope since some nested directive need to access it and I would prefer not to modify my list directive with a bunch of exception, only an override function (onItemClick);

Right now it's not working, the stateparams don't get assigned.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't isolate scope and use "&" bingind, you should use $parser service.

First parse attribute:

```
var onItemClick = $parse($attrs.onItemClick);
```

then call it like this:

```
onItemClick($scope, { item: item });
```

You pass your context scope as the first argument, and an object containing local (per call) variables the second argument.

And not to polute outer scope, you can use "child scope", by specifying `scope: true` in directive definition.